# Cutting timestamps into minute by minute interval per row with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a spark dataframe which has two columns: start_time and end_time. I am wondering how can I split and effectively cutting timestamps into minute intervals (time between start_time and end_time in pyspark TimestampType) per id using some form of rounding (taking the ceiling, in this instance) and assign it as a new column called minutes in pyspark?

```
#sample data
 val df0 = Seq(
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:00:00", "2020-04-14 19:23:59"),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:24:00", "2020-04-14 19:26:59"),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:27:00", "2020-04-14 19:35:59"),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:36:00", "2020-04-14 19:55:00"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 08:00:00", "2020-04-15 08:02:59"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 11:03:00", "2020-04-15 11:11:59"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 11:12:00", "2020-04-15 11:45:59"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 11:46:00", "2020-04-15 11:47:00")
    ).toDF("id", "date", "start_time", "end_time")
```

Here is desired output

```
      datetime  id       start_time        end_time            minutes
1  2020-04-14  78aa 2020-04-14 19:00:00 2020-04-14 19:23:59 2020-04-14 19:00:00
2  2020-04-14  78aa 2020-04-14 19:00:00 2020-04-14 19:23:59 2020-04-14 19:01:00
3  2020-04-14  78aa 2020-04-14 19:00:00 2020-04-14 19:23:59 2020-04-14 19:02:00
4  2020-04-14  78aa 2020-04-14 19:00:00 2020-04-14 19:23:59 2020-04-14 19:03:00
5  2020-04-14  78aa 2020-04-14 19:00:00 2020-04-14 19:23:59 2020-04-14 19:04:00
6  2020-04-14  78aa 2020-04-14 19:00:00 2020-04-14 19:23:59 2020-04-14 19:05:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this helps-

> Written in scala but can be ported to python with minimal changes.

More explanation - [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sequence)

```scala
  val df0 = Seq(
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:00:00", "2020-04-14 19:23:59"),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:24:00", "2020-04-14 19:26:59"),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:27:00", "2020-04-14 19:35:59"),
      ("78aa", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-14 19:36:00", "2020-04-14 19:55:00"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 08:00:00", "2020-04-15 08:02:59"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 11:03:00", "2020-04-15 11:11:59"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 11:12:00", "2020-04-15 11:45:59"),
      ("25aa", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-15 11:46:00", "2020-04-15 11:47:00")
    ).toDF("id", "date", "start_time", "end_time")

    df0.withColumn("minutes",
      explode(sequence($"start_time".cast("timestamp"), $"end_time".cast("timestamp"), expr("interval 1 minute"))))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |id  |date      |start_time         |end_time           |minutes            |
      * +----+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:00:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:01:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:02:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:03:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:04:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:05:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:06:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:07:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:08:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:09:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:10:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:11:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:12:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:13:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:14:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:15:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:16:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:17:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:18:00|
      * |78aa|2020-04-14|2020-04-14 19:00:00|2020-04-14 19:23:59|2020-04-14 19:19:00|
      * +----+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * only showing top 20 rows
      */
```